# Value error: The truth value of a series is ambiguous. Use a.empyt,a.bool(), a.utem(), a.any(), or a.all()

Tags: python, pandas

I was trying to apply a function in python that checks for multiple conditions across different columns in a dataframe and returns a value.

```
df= pd.DataFrame(data)

def function(data):
    if data['product']= product1:
        If data['tenure']> 4:
            return 19

X= df.apply(function)
```

What am I doing wrong?

I changed logical and conditions with Boolean &.
Also tried converting each column into series inside the function as I thought apply will only take series instead of dataframe but again I got confused and this didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

you need to compare with ==

```
product1="some value"

df= pd.DataFrame(data)

def function(data):
    if data['product']== product1:
        If data['tenure']> 4:
            return 19

X= df.apply(function)
```